# How can I clip text and append an ellipsis when it is longer than desired?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking for a good way to append an ellipsis, "...",  when I need to gracefully display a string that is too large and doesn't fit in the space that I want.

The way that I'm currently doing that is looking for a max length of characters that will fit in the space, then cut the string to that length and append the "..." .  All that in the server-side.

In pseudocode should look like:

```
// I define this MAXCHARS var value by hunch
String outputString = MyLengthyString.SubString(0, MAXCHARS)
outputString.concatenate("...")
view.aLabelInThePage = outputString
```

The problem is when I'm not using fixed-length fonts, it could be displayed not in the way that I want (occupying all the space).

Is there any way to get the desired results only using JavaScript and CSS? If not, is there a better way than mine?

Comment: Think you meant "append" instead of "postpend"...

Comment: @Hello71: Editing, I'm sorry. It should be a mistake since English is not my native language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [CSS3 `text-overflow` property](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-overflow/) with a value of `ellipsis`.  This property was [introduced in IE6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531174(VS.85).aspx) and later adopted by other major browsers, with Firefox 7 being the most recent to add support for it:

```
#mySpan {
  /* IE 6+, Opera 11+, Chrome 1+, Safari 1.3+, Firefox 7+ */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  /* IE 8    */ -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /* Opera 9 */ -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Firefox 9 will be the first browser to implement the two-value syntax for this property, allowing both left and right sides of the text to have a value, though this syntax is currently noted as at-risk by the [working draft specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#text-overflow0).

---

[This page](http://chetzit.com/blog/css/9.html) has a non-JS solution for older Firefox versions, but it's not perfect and has a couple of limitations.

Comment: @The: I just added a link to my answer for a Firefox solution.  I found a few others, but they were buggy and caused problems in the browsers that do support ellipsis.

Comment: Firefox 7 finally supports it too.

Comment: @c69: thanks for letting me know, I've updated the answer to improve the listed browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, but it's not supported by Firefox.

Comment: Probably by the "How dare you recommend using something that's not supported by my favourite browser" brigade. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Will the jquery width command work, along with a second span tag that just shows the "..."?

```
if ($("#mySpan").width() > 400) {
     $("mySpan").width(400);
     $("mySpanEllipsis").show();
} 
else {
     $("mySpanEllipsis").hide();
}
```

And your HTML looks like

```
<span id="mySpan"></span><span id="mySpanEllipsis">...</span>
```

Not tested, so use at your own risk :-).