# Work out how many characters can fit into DIV with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, character

Does anyone know what the best method would be to work out how many characters can fit inside a DIV block in HTML using JavaScript?

Any advise would greatly help.

Comment: Does the div have predefined width?

Comment: Do you want to limit the no. of characters going into a DIV or you want to check and flag a message to user if the content is more than the DIV can take?

Comment: If you're trying to truncate a string down to fit in a div, you should look at better alternatives - such as the CSS3 property *text-overflow*, which is supported in IE6+ and most modern browsers.  See [my answer to *Append "..." when a string is larger than desired* for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247011/append-when-a-string-is-larger-than-desired/3247062#3247062)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iteratively add your characters to a hidden div and check the width of that. Not sure if there is a better way.

Edit: Something like this:

```
var targetWidth = document.getElementById('DivToCheck').clientWidth;
var stringToFit = 'abcdefghijk';
var numChars = 0;
for(var i=0; i < stringToFit.length; i++)
{
   document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').innerHTML += stringToFit.charAt(i);
   if (document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').clientWidth > targetWidth)
   {
       numChars = i - 1;
       break;
   }
}

<div id="hiddenDiv" style="visibility: hidden; width: auto;"></div>
```

Comment: bear in mind the following: 1. the hidden div will affect the layout of the page, and so should have *position:absolute;* and, 2. The hidden div will need to match the font stylings of the div to check (e.g. *font-family*, *font-size*, *font-weight*, etc).