# How to paginate text in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, scrollbar

Assume I have the text of War and Peace in a variable `wandp`.

Is there any way of writing a function such that `page(n)` would return exactly the correct amount of text to fill the current browser window, where `n` is a character index into `wandp`.

I want the text to be the correct amount, i.e. no significant whitespace or scrollbars.

I suppose I'm looking for a text description of an ebook algorithm for browsers.

P.S. I'm sure there are complications around chapters and other layout features, but they can wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing an idea from [Work out how many characters can fit into DIV with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403789/work-out-how-many-characters-can-fit-into-div-with-javascript), I would create a hidden `<div>` and set the width of that element equal to the browser window width. Then, I would create a function to add text from `wandp`, checking the height of the `<div>` element as you append, until the height of the `<div>` element is equal to the browser window height.

It might look something like this:

**HTML:**

```
...
<div id="normalDiv" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden"></div>
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="visibility: hidden; width: 100%;"></div>
...
```

**Javascript:**

```
...
var targetHeight = window.innerHeight - 40; //browser window height minus height of last line of text
var wandp = 'The entire content of War and Peace...';
var startChar = 0;
var endChar = 0;
for(var i=startChar; i < wandp.length; i++){
    endChar = i;
    document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').innerHTML += wandp.charAt(i);
    if (document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').clientHeight > targetHeight){
        endChar--;
        break;
    }
}
document.getElementById('normalDiv').innerHTML = wandp.substring(startChar, endChar);
...
```

Keep in mind, this will result in cut-off text since it will go up to the absolute last character that will fit the constraints. You will need to get a little creative in order to end the text on the page at a reasonable character (last period encountered, before last whitespace encountered, etc).