# How to dynamically add pages | multiple pages on one page

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Is there any way to dynamically have multiple 'pages' (they can be just `divs`) contained within a wrapper? For example, suppose I have a website with a `textarea` for the user to enter information. I would then like to display that information in a div with a fixed width and height. Whenever the height of the text exceeds the height of the div that it is displayed in, I would like to dynamically add another div to display the remainder of the text. So, something like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <span>
      <strong>Add text:</strong>
    </span>
    <textarea v-model="text" id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="6" cols="50" />
  </div>

  <div v-for="page in pages" :key="page" class="page">
    <span>
      <strong>Page 1</strong>
    </span>
    <div class="editor-area">{{text}}</div>

    <!-- So ideally, when the 'text height' exceeds the height of the div,
    I would like to add a 'second page'. The text that 'overflows' the first 
    page, should be added to the second page.-->

  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like it to be dynamic, so that the user can type as much as he wants.

I prepared a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-cartwright-7ms6w?file=/src/App.vue) that has basic code for my use case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a poor implementation to work on, it has two problems that you'll still have to solve:

1. A proper count of the amount of characters that fit your fixed div:

`aproxlength` should contain the approximated number of characters your fixed div can fit. You can enter here an approximated number from your experience on your browser, but that's not universal.

Solving accurately this problem is not so trivial as it will change between browsers and graphic units. The proper way to go seams to recreate a hidden div and fill it until it overflows, then you'll have a precise answer to the proper `aproxlength` for each client. [Related implementation on pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403789/work-out-how-many-characters-can-fit-into-div-with-javascript)

2. A proper way to split text:

Do not split the text as I did, because it will split the text madly. You have to split it on the prior whitespace, or point.

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
      <span>
        <strong>Add text:</strong>
      </span>
      <textarea id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="6" cols="50" v-model="text"/>
    </div>

    <div v-for="page in pagesc" :key="page" class="page">
      <span>
        <strong>Page 1</strong>
      </span>
      <div class="editor-area">{{text.slice((page-1)*aproxlength,page*aproxlength)}}</div>

      <!-- So ideally, when the 'text height' exceeds the height of the div,
    I would like to add a 'second page'. The text that 'overflows' the first 
      page, should be added to the second page.-->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pages: 1,
      aproxlength: 330,
      text:
        "Lorem Ipsum is simply simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic."
    };
  },
  computed: {
    pagesc() {
      return Math.floor(this.text.length/this.aproxlength)+1
    }
  }
};
</script>
```